# how to use variable inside kivy load string

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random

count=0
counto=0


Builder.load_string("""
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        size:root.width,root.height
        padding:50
        spacing:20
        Button:
            on_press:root.rock()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
            Image:
                source:'rock.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
        Button:
            on_press:root.scissor()
            Image:
                source:'scissor.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
        Button:
            on_press:root.paper()
            Image:
                source:'paper.png'
                center_x:self.parent.center_x
                center_y:self.parent.center_y
                width: 200
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                y: self.parent.y 
                x: self.parent.x
                keep_ratio:False
                allow_stretch: False
<score>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Goto settings'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.current = 'menu'
            Button:
                text: 'Quit'
        Label:
            text:app.count
        Label:
            text:'AI score'+app.counto
        Label:
            text:app.count2




""")


class MyLayout(Screen):

    def rock(self):
        RPS=['rock','scissor','paper']
        z=random.choice(RPS)
        y='rock'
        print(z,y)
        if z==y:
            print("draw")
        elif z=='rock':
            if y=='paper':
                print("you won")
                global count
                count+=1
                count2=str(count)
                print(count)
            elif y=='scissor':
                global counto
                print('you lost')
                counto+=1
                print(counto)
        elif z=='paper':
            if y=='scissor':
                print("you won")
                count+=1
                print(count)
            elif y=='rock':
                print('you lost')
                counto+=1
                print(counto)
        elif z=='scissor':
            if y=='rock':
                print("you won")
                count+=1
                print(count)
            elif y=='paper':
                print('you lost')
                counto+=1
                print(counto)

    def paper(self):
        RPS=['rock','scissor','paper']
        z=random.choice(RPS)
        y='paper'
        print(z,y)
        if z==y:
            print("draw")
        elif z=='rock':
            if y=='paper':
                print("you won")
            elif y=='scissor':
                print('you lost')
        elif z=='paper':
            if y=='scissor':
                print("you won")
            elif y=='rock':
                print('you lost')
        elif z=='scissor':
            if y=='rock':
                print("you won")
            elif y=='paper':
                print('you lost')

    def scissor(self):
        RPS=['rock','scissor','paper']
        z=random.choice(RPS)
        y='scissor'
        print(z,y)
        if z==y:
            print("draw")
        elif z=='rock':
            if y=='paper':
                print("you won")
            elif y=='scissor':
                print('you lost')
        elif z=='paper':
            if y=='scissor':
                print("you won")
            elif y=='rock':
                print('you lost')
        elif z=='scissor':
            if y=='rock':
                print("you won")
            elif y=='paper':
                print('you lost')
        

class score(Screen):
    pass
    
class AwesomeApp(App):
    count=StringProperty()
    count2=StringProperty()
    counto=StringProperty()

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MyLayout(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(score(name='settings'))
        return sm


if __name__=='__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Why are `count`, `count2` and `counto` not being displayed? Can someone explain that?
I tried the method of `StringProperty` and then using that to access the variable but it is displaying nothing.

Comment: Please don't copy same text multiple times into your question. If it asks you to enter more text, it definitely does not mean that you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count` and `counto` variables are just variables, and changing their values will have no effect on the `Labels` in your `score` Screen. Those `Labels` will display the value of the `stringProperties` that you have defined, but you must actually change those values in order for those `Labels` to show changed values. For example, in your `MyLayout` Screen:

```
class MyLayout(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.app = App.get_running_app()  # just a convenient way to set the app variable

    def rock(self):
        RPS = ['rock', 'scissor', 'paper']
        z = random.choice(RPS)
        y = 'rock'
        print(z, y)
        if z == y:
            print("draw")
        elif z == 'rock':
            if y == 'paper':
                print("you won")
                global count
                count += 1
                self.app.count2 = str(count)  # change the StringProperty
                print(count)
.
.
.
```

Comment: thank you for youre explaination after understanding what you had written i surfed the internet once more and understood what to do finally it is working only one ore functionality i need to add thank you

Comment: Just here again to thank you